# Is is possible to pass one string as two arguments in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, is it possible to define a string as $mystring="param1 param2"
then pass that string to a process call

& c:\usr\bin\myprocess.exe "$mystring"

and have it interpreted as myprocess.exe param1 param2?
where param1 and param2 are separate arguments

Comment: I think that's going to depend on how myprocess.exe parses it's arguments.

Comment: You may want to check out http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/, but I would agree with @mjolinor that it will fundamentally depend on how myexternalprocess.exe. Any reason why you would not define your params as an array e.g. $mystring=@("param1","param2") then just use & c:\usr\bin\myprocess.exe $mystring

Comment: Interesting; I recently [wrote something quite similar to that](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) (including a companion executable to really see the arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you pass argument array to `Start-Process` with the `-ArgumentList` parameter; e.g.:

```
$argList = "param1","param2"
start-process myprocess.exe $argList
```